# Creation a 2D mesh with pyvista and coloring different groups of cells with different colors

Tags: python

I need to create a 2D quadratic mesh (let's say 20x10 elements) and color different groups of cells by different colors (first 50 elements : blue, 51 to 100 : red and the rest green) using pyvista.

I spent days on the pyvista documentation but it's really not organised and the coloring documentations aren't compatible with the unstructured mesh and so it is a mess.

I would appreciate any help, thanks !

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Ok to rescale the problem to a 2x2 mesh (4 squares), I need to create a 2x2 squared mesh using pyvista, then let's say color the first square green, the second one blue, the third and forth red.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a regular 2D mesh with square cells using the `pyvista.Plane`.  Data in PyVista is stored either on the points or the cells.  Since you want to color the cells, you want to use cell data.  Then when you plot, you can pass `rgb=True` to plot the data according to rgb coloring.  If you use the default `rgb=False`, then PyVista will treat the data as general vector valued data.

Here is sample code that generates a 2x2 grid of cells and places colors (red, green, blue, and yellow) on the cells.  Then plots it.

```py
import pyvista

mesh = pyvista.Plane(i_resolution=2, j_resolution=2)
mesh.cell_data["colors"] = [
    [1.0, 0, 0],
    [0, 1, 0],
    [0, 0, 1],
    [1, 1, 0]
]

plotter = pyvista.Plotter()
plotter.add_mesh(mesh, scalars="colors", rgb=True)
plotter.view_xy()
plotter.show()
```

[image: pyvista screenshot]